# Asynchronous (event driven) data reception from FTDI device using D2XX (FTD2XX_NET)

Tags: c#, .net, ftdi

Is there a way of using the D2XX .NET library (`FTD2XX_NET`) to carry out asynchronous operations on an FTDI device?

Currently, from what I can tell, this can only be done with an FTDI device in VCP (Virtual Com Port) mode and opening it as a COM port.

Since we have purposefully not enabled VCP on some of our FTDI devices, this is not always a suitable alternative.

Currently (using pure D2XX), the only way I can see to get any async operation is to have a worker thread polling the `GetRxBytesAvailable` method and `Read`ing when `RxQueue` returns non-zero. Then when data is received, an `OnDataReceived` event can be raised to upper layers.

Comment: No, it is a very thin wrapper that adds no .NET goodies.  Yes on the thread.  No on the polling, use Read() or SetEventNotification().

Comment: `SetEventNotification` looks like the answer I'm looking for - missed that; I'll give it a go...